# The transition animation in Image Gallery with Vertical Thumbnail

Tags: jssor

Is there anyway to disable the transition animation in "Image Gallery with Vertical Thumbnail"? Here I mean the large photo part, not the thumbnail part. Currently the left-right animation makes me a little dizzy especially when switching more photos.

Besides, I wonder if the animation could be fade in/out effect? Say, now I am at the 1st photo and I click the thumbnail of the 5th photo. In the large photo part, the 1st photo fades out and the 5th photo fades in.

Comment: Sharing some code is key... if there's nothing to see, we can't suggest changes.

Comment: Sliding left<-->right is the basic feature of jssor slider. For now, it should switch slide by sliding according to a manual navigation request. And we have plan to enable the feature you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for the answering. At lease now I know I am not in the wrong direction. Looking forward to the new feature.